# Use webpack bundled CSS only in scope of webcomponent

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

I'm using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to bundle a webcomponent (created using [preact-custom-element](https://github.com/bspaulding/preact-custom-element)) and its style.

I'm able to use the component successfully in a separate html file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <script async src="./webcomponent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <custom-menu name="Test"></custom-menu>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `custom-menu` tag is my webcomponent. It shows the styled custom component as expected.

However, I want to know if there is a possibility to apply my custom CSS (inserted using the extracted `styles.css` file) only to the custom element and not allowing the style to potentially overwrite other styles belonging to html elements outside the webcomponent.

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        webcomponent: './lib/menu/menu-panel-webcomponent-controller.widget.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'widget/')
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
};
```

It takes my custom component `menu-panel-webcomponent-controller.widget.js` and applies the `extract` function of the `ExtractTextPlugin` to all css files. The resulting bundle alongside the style `styles.css` is then found inside the `widget/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found:

I found [preact shadow dom](https://github.com/bspaulding/preact-shadow-dom) which allows the implementation of a shadow DOM. A shadow DOM allows scoped CSS, which means that the CSS is only bound to the component and can neither be influenced from the outside nor can it leak outside its scope.

However, note that MS Edge has currently no support for shadow DOM (see their [roadmap](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/shadowdom/)).

I also found that local CSS scoping can be done using webpack only as well. See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader. However, the loader explicitly replaces local selectors with unique identifiers.

Example:

```
:local(.className) {
  background: red;
}
```

results in:

```
._23_aKvs-b8bW2Vg3fwHozO {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work with only css this feature is not change class name in html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).